# Find the least upper bound for $P(X\ge 3)$ when $X\ge 2$ and $E[X]=2.5$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Find the least upper bound for $P(X\ge3)$ when $X\ge 2$ and $E[X]=2.5$.

What I have tried so far is:

Modify $X$ and apply Markov's inequality to upper bound $P(X\ge 3)$, where Markov's inequality says $P(X\ge a)\le \mu/a$.

Thus, I assumed the answer is $~2.53/3~$ but that answer is incorrect.

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please read about how to format your posts [according to the rules of the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=P(X\ge 3)$.

From $E[X]=2.5$, we get
$$3p+2(1-p)\le 2.5$$
which yields $p \le \frac{1}{2}$.

The upper bound is sharp since $X$ could be such that $P(X=2)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X=3)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Note that for a given nonnegative random variable $X$, Markov's inequality gives an upper bound, but not necessarily the least upper bound.

Thus, applying Markov's inequality for the given $X$, we get
$$P(X\ge 3)\le {\small{\frac{\mu_X}{3}}}={\small{\frac{2.5}{3}}}={\small{\frac{5}{6}}}$$
which is true, but not best possible, since it doesn't take into account the restriction $X\ge 2$.

However, Markov's inequality *can* be successfully used here by making the change $Y=X-2$.

Then $E[Y]=\frac{1}{2}$, hence by Markov's inequality
$$P(X\ge 3)=P(Y\ge 1) \le {\small{\frac{\mu_Y}{1}}} = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}$$